# Web Scraping: Why is the find command not getting the expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm beginning to work on a scraping script for my club. I will hopefully create a script that can collect all the data from by club teams and make my data analysis easier. I'm working on the code below, however I'm struggling to get the text from "actaEquipos". My code should collect the home team and the away team which I will later add into an excel sheet, but I'm stuck on the first step.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Stylesheet
import requests, openpyxl

excel   =  openpyxl.Workbook()
print(excel.sheetnames)
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = "Acta Partido"
print (excel.sheetnames)

try:

    source = requests.get('https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2022/futbol-11/cadet-primera-divisio/grup-2/1c/sant-ignasi-ce-a/1c/lhospitalet-centre-esports-b')

    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

    actaEquipos = soup.find_all('div', class_='acta-equip')
    actaMarcador = soup.find('div', class_='acta-marcador').text
    acta = soup.find_all('table', class_='acta-table')
    
    print(actaEquipos)

    for equipo in actaEquipos:
        nombreEquipo = equipo.find('span', class_='tr').txt

        print(nombreEquipo)
        print(len(actaEquipos))
        break

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

excel.save('ActaPartido.xlsx')
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and scrape, scraper, scraped) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish, or fighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

There is just a typo in your code that should get the text - There is no error shown, cause result of selection is `None`

#### How to fix?

Fix typo by adding an e to txt:

```
nombreEquipo = equipo.find('span', class_='tr').text
```

Comment: Thanks!! Why didn't I get any error?

Comment: Happy to help - Updated the answer ->  "There is no error shown, cause result of selection is `None`"

Comment: I will need to rethink the approach for this step. I need to extract the home and away team from class 'acta-equip' and the html code is different for the home and away. In addition the find all has a length of 4 elements and I just need the first 2 elements

Comment: This would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) how to deal with it - *quick and dirty you can just slice the resultset of `find_all(...)[:2]`*

Comment: I found a more simpler way! Thanks